# No error message is displayed, the server only returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, symfony

I have set up a new Symfony3 project locally, but when I'm getting something wrong in my code the error is not displayed, only

> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Is any other setting is required to display the exact error message on page?

Comment: Check your Logs! For the best error logging experience, set error_reporting to -1, turn display_errors off, and set a custom error_log. Then in the terminal, type 'tail -f /path/to/error_log'. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display. Then update your question with the actual error message from PHP

Comment: _but when I'm getting something wrong in my code the error is not displayed, only_ In that case it would be a good idea to show us your code

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `app_dev.php` instead of `app.php`, so in your web browser enter the `yourdomain.dev/app_dev.php` instead of `yourdomain.dev`.

Comment: Really just a comment, dont you agree?

Comment: Is it not an answer for this question? He wants to see errors in dev environment which Symfony Framework simply provides.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - It actually is the answer.  For some reason the op is running in production mode instead of development mode.  "show us your code" is not helpful in this case as it is almost certainly a system configuration issue.

Comment: Switching to app_dev.php will not necessarily show any further information on a 500 error because 500 errors can be caused by services earlier in the lifecycle than the symfony bootstrap. It is a good suggestion, but not a definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error could be caused earlier in the request lifecycle than your application code, so it may not be possible to report further information "on page" depending on what service is failing. Those services may have their own settings for further error reporting in the response body; however, logs are typically the best place to look for services outside of the application code.

Turning on error reporting for your application as well, which, as @miikes suggested, in a standard symfony app can be done by using /app_dev.php instead of /app.php, could potentially provide more information if the error is in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Read your server service logs (e.g. `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`) because 500 can be triggered by error on each level of your architecture (low on the server side or high in the app).

If you have errors in the application, very helpful would be set `debug=true` to the AppKernel (so you can just launch your application via app_dev.php instead of default app.php).